# UIImagePicker Controller with the Delete option

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building an app which takes the image from the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` . When I select the Image I have to display the Image in another view with the Delete button . Please refer the below image . My intension is if you observe the photos app in the iPhone after selecting the image it is going to the fullImage view . Can we display the same in the app using the UIImagePickerController?

[image]

I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution . Is there any frameworks existing for showing full Image with the Delete symbol . I am trying to implement my own view, but it is taking much time to implement .

Answer (score 0):

See this library

[FGallery](http://code4app.net/ios/Image-Gallery/4f67f4546803fa6d45000001)

There is the trash button which you are looking. You need to do only small changes for your requirement

Comment: Thank you @manujmv but I have to display the images from SavedPhotosAlbum and when I clicked on delete it has to delete from SavedPhotosAlbum

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't actually allow you to delete from the photo library through an API. The user has to actually go to the Photos app and delete it manually themselves. Apple does allow you write to the photo library:

> To save a still image to the user’s Saved Photos album, use the
>   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. 
>        To save a movie to the user’s Saved Photos album, use the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function.

But for deleting and editing/overriding an existing photo, Apple doesn't have anything like that right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected image from your library, you have to dismiss your 
UIImagePickerController and after that you need to create custom UIViewController and you have to present/push it to the user with saved picture:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

    UIImage *_image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    UICustomViewController *custom = [[UICustomViewController alloc] init];
    custom.MyImage = _image;
    [self presentViewController:custom animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It's very simple solution and you don't needy to use any existing framework.

Comment: Thank you @Greg  when I clicked on delete it has to delete from SavedPhotosAlbum

Comment: I afraid Apple doesn't let you to do that from any API. You can just do it from the 'Photos' app.